# url em projeto MVC de um .html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

gostaria de criar um .html que vai servir para ser o menu do _Layout.cshtml, vou chamar ele através de  `$("#IDMenu").load('menu_Home.html');`

Minha pergunta, qual melhor lugar para deixa-lo?
posso deixa-lo na pasta

```
/Shared/ ?
_Layout.cshtml
menu_home.html
menu_admin.html
```

e nessa masterpage _Layout.cshtml, como chamaria ele?

```
/views/Shared/menu_home.html `não funcionou`
Shared/menu_home.html `não funcionou`
```

Comment: É realmente necessário usar o `load()` do jQuery pra fazer isso ou pode ser feito de outra forma?

Comment: Existe algum motivo para que isso não seja uma partial view?

Comment: poderia ser, vou ler sobre o assunto. é um conteúdo estático.

Comment: Eu deixaria ele na Shared, porque ela pode servir para outras páginas.

Comment: O thiago.adriano26 que saber que erro deu. Seria útil para todos poderem te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Não dá erro, porém chamar uma page .html via jquery.load da como 404, enfim, a url não é acessivel acho que por não ter uma controler e esta dentro da pasta views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for estático, use no seu arquivo `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Html.Partial("_Menu")
```

Crie para este caso um arquivo `_Menu.cshtml`

Se for dinâmico, use uma `Action`:

```
@Html.Action("Menu")
```

Crie para este caso um `Controller` comum e coloque nele uma `Action` que popule este menu:

```
namespace MeuProjeto.Controllers
{
    public class CommonController : Controller
    {
        private MeuProjetoContext context = new MeuProjetoContext();

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Menu()
        {
            var menu = context.EntradasDoMenu.ToList();

            return PartialView(menu);
        }
    }
}
```

Crie também uma View chamada `Shared\Menu.cshtml` que receba um Model do tipo `IEnumerable<EntradaDoMenu>` (usei esse nome no meu exemplo, mas você pode criar um Model com o nome que quiser):

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.EntradaDoMenu>

<ul>
    @foreach (var entrada in Model) { 
       <li>@Html.ActionLink(entrada.Nome, "Index", entrada.NomeDoController)</li>
    }
</ul>
```